# How to make multiple DropDownList change based on selection from other DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have the following ASP.net code which I am using to filter my `GridView`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TasksUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: separate;" class="GridviewTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Task Name" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateTaskName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2739] 'Task Name' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateService" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Service" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateService" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2846] 'Service' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 11%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateStatus" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Status" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2812] 'Status' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 14%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDueDate" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateDueDate" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Due Date" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDueDate_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDueDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), [ATTR2752], 110) 'Due Date' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOwner" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateOwner" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Owner" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOwner_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateOwner" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [REALNAME] 'Owner' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateClient" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Client" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateClient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2799] 'Client' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My code-behind for the ASP.net page above:

```
protected void ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "";
    string strText = ddlTaskName.SelectedItem.Text;
    ddlService.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlClient.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlOwner.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //MessageBox.Show(strText);

    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    if (strText == "All")
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2739 = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (ViewState["sortExp"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlOwner_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "";
    string strText = ddlOwner.SelectedItem.Text;
    ddlService.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlClient.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //MessageBox.Show(strText);

    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    if (strText == "All")
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND UA.REALNAME = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (ViewState["sortExp"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "";
    string strText = ddlService.SelectedItem.Text;
    ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlClient.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlOwner.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //MessageBox.Show(strText);

    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    if (strText == "All")
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2846 = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (ViewState["sortExp"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlStatus_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "";
    string strText = ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text;
    ddlService.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlClient.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlOwner.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //MessageBox.Show(strText);

    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    if (strText == "All")
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2812 = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (ViewState["sortExp"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlDueDate_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "";
    string strText = ddlDueDate.SelectedItem.Text;
    ddlService.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlClient.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlOwner.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //MessageBox.Show(strText);

    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    if (strText == "All")
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (ViewState["sortExp"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlClient_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "";
    string strText = ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text;
    ddlService.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlOwner.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //MessageBox.Show(strText);

    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    if (strText == "All")
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2799 = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (ViewState["sortExp"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The function which does the filtering of the `GridView`:

```
public void PullData(string sortExp, string sortDir)
{
    string query = "";
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    connString = ""; //the connection string is here
    if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlService.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlOwner.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlClient.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlTaskName.SelectedItem.Text;
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2739 = '" + strText + "'";
    }
    else if (ddlService.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlService.SelectedItem.Text;
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2846 = '" + strText + "'";
    }
    else if (ddlStatus.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text;
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2812 = '" + strText + "'";
    }
    else if (ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlDueDate.SelectedItem.Text;
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) = '" + strText + "'";
    }
    else if (ddlOwner.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text;
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND UA.REALNAME = '" + strText + "'";
    }
    else if (ddlClient.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text;
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ATTR2799 = '" + strText + "'";
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (sortExp != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, when a user choose an option from one of the `DropDownList`'s the other `DropDownList` will change to the values for the filtered `GridView` but because the `DataSource` is hard coded in, I am not able to do it.

How do I filter each of the `DropDownList`'s from the filtered `GridView` once any selection of the `DropDownList` has been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd thoroughly advise you to use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx), this should work for you (perhaps with minor adjustments as I can't see the entirety of your code, of course)

This method should generate a valid where clause.  You can use this method in the various `OnSelectedIndexChanged` methods in your code-behind to prevent a lot of copy/pasted code.

```
public string GenerateWhereClause()
{
    List<String> conditions = new List<String>();

    conditions.Add("(CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0)");

    if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlTaskName.SelectedItem.Text;
        conditions.Add(String.Format("(CT.ATTR2739 = '{0}')", strText));
    }

    if (ddlService.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlService.SelectedItem.Text;
        conditions.Add(String.Format("(CT.ATTR2846 = '{0}')", strText));
    }

    if (ddlStatus.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text;
        conditions.Add(String.Format("(CT.ATTR2812 = '{0}')", strText));
    }

    if (ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlDueDate.SelectedItem.Text;
        conditions.Add(String.Format("(CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) = '{0}')", strText));
    }

    if (ddlOwner.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlOwner.SelectedItem.Text;
        conditions.Add(String.Format("(UA.REALNAME = '{0}')", strText));
    }

    if (ddlClient.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strText = ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text;
        conditions.Add(String.Format("(CT.ATTR2799 = '{0}')", strText));
    }

    // You can add additional filters here.  This isn't the cleanest way of doing it, but it's fairly quick and easy as long as you don't intend to add many more filters.

    string conditionsJoined = String.Join(" AND ", conditions);
    string whereClause = String.Format(" WHERE {0}", conditionsJoined);
    return whereClause;
}
```

And this is a modified version of your `PullData` method. (note that I've only changed the top portion where it creates the conditional statement.

```
public void PullData(string sortExp, string sortDir)
{
    string query = String.Format("{0}{1}", strMainQuery, GenerateWhereClause());
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    connString = ""; //the connection string is here

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (sortExp != string.Empty)
            {
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I intending on doing once I figured out how to change the DropDownList option based on the filtered GridView. How do I filter the DropDownList based on the filtered GridView?